# How to process the redirect in post method using HttpClient?

Tags: http, post, httpclient

In My App , I POST a xml file to the server , but sometimes the server will send back 302 and then redirect .

However , after the redirecting the method become GET , not POST, and my data in xml file can't deliver to server.

And finally the status code I got is 404.

Is there some way to process the redirect by myself ? Can I do something when the redirecting is happening?

Anyone can help? THX.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3):

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Are you sure your server isn't using the '[POST, redirect, GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)' idiom?

You can [disable automatic following of redirects](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d4e1192) in Apache HTTP client. For example:

```
_httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
_httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
    ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution I could use since my HttpClient is generated by a factory, which I do not wish to override (part of spring framework), so I only have access to it post construction.

Comment: just in case anyone reads this: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893624/1087479 I had to edit my answer covering a similar topic, because RFC 2616 is replaced by RFC 7231-35.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, 302's should not be treated as an instruction to perform the redirected request as a GET, that is what 303's are for. This behaviour is sloppy and the developers of HttpClient should be ashamed of themselves... :-P

I suspect your only option would be write your own, socket level implementation of an HTTP Client, that handles the redirects properly. You can have a look round the internet to see if anyone else has already produced to some code you can borrow, but if not you will have to do it yourself.

I have done this before in PHP - it's not actually that hard, HTTP is a fairly simple protocol to implement. I think cURL handles these redirects properly, if you can sub the task out to that?