# Auto Redirection with Apache HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

I am using apache HttpClient with my Android 4.2 application. I have a requirement to support auto-redirection of requests. I am setting the auto redirection flag on the request as follows:

```
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(this.request.getParams(), isAutoRedirectEnabled);
```

The requests redirect fine as long as the request is a simple GET. When I send a POST request with a certain payload, the first request goes as a POST, but when that requests gets redirected, the auto redirect logic sends a GET request to the redirected URL.

I tried setting the HttpRedirectHandler to the DefaultHttpClient and handle the re-directions manually, but this is a very hacky way of doing it and I am discovering issues in it already. Is there another way?

Comment: pretty much the same question as [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105096/how-to-process-the-redirect-in-post-method-using-httpclient