# Different HTTP response from Android app and Java application

Tags: java, android, http

I am writing an Android app that needs to authenticate with a server by sending a HTTP POST request.

When run as a regular Java application on my desktop I get a 200 OK response code when the username and password are valid, and a 302 Found when they are not (from the browser, entering invalid username/password redirects to a page that says you are unauthorized).

However, when run from my Android app I get a 200 OK every time regardless of the validity of the password.

Here is the code:

```
public static boolean authenticate(String user, String pass) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://website.com/login");

    try
    {
        // Add form parameters to request
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("basic", "true"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair ("j_password", pass));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));


        // execute post request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("POST RESPONSE STATUS = " + status + ": " + response.getStatusLine().toString());

        // success if we get 200 OK
        // something went wrong if we get a 302 Found
        if (status == 200) {
            return true;
        } else if (status == 302) {
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown response status: " + status);
            return false;
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("IOException trying to authenticate: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using netcat, I tried sending the request to my own computer to inspect the headers.

When executed from desktop this is what is sent:

```
kyle@kyle-Rev-1-0 ~ $ nc -l -p 8080
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 192.168.2.17:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)

basic=true&j_username=bob14&j_password=meow%21
```

When executed on my Android 4.1 tablet this is sent:

```
kyle@kyle-Rev-1-0 ~ $ nc -l -p 8080
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 192.168.2.17:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

basic=true&j_username=bob14&j_password=meow%21
```

I thought it might be related to the user agent, I tried an empty string as well as "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)" and neither made a difference.

The project is setup in Eclipse to use libraries httpcore-4.2.2.jar and httpclient-4.2.3.jar.  The Android project also depends on commons-httpclient-3.1.jar at the moment.

Does anyone see why the requests are getting me different responses?

Comment: There has to be something you aren't showing us. The `User-Agent` really shouldn't be affecting the request.

Comment: Use something like the Firefox Live HTTP Headers addon and record the Desktop request response in both cases - right and wrong passwords. Compare that to the request/response from your tablet. It might as well be that the target website redirects the request from your app user agent to mobile site or the site itself gives different response to your app's mobile user agent. Trying Desktop user agent from the app is another idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Android HttpClient class doesn't redirect by default when you POST over https.

Try without SSL for test purposes.

[Here's another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106363/2648782)

Comment: Actually the problem is the HttpClient IS following redirects by default on Android.  Great link, I was able to solve my problem by adding the following line:

`HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(post.getParams(), false);`