# c# httpclient PostAsJson sending GET request instead of POST

Tags: c#, json, http, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to make a post request. I get back 405 method not allowed. When capturing a trace in fiddler, it goes out as GET instead of POST!

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = AppSettingsUtil.GetString("url");
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, transaction).Result;
            }
```

I am aware of the async/await issues. This is a simplified sample to show the issue.

Is there some sort of web.config or machine.config setting that could be affecting this? Other requests (sent through RestSharp) send Posts correctly

Here is what fiddler captures. Rerunning the trace in fiddler also returns the 405 (as expected). Manually switching it to POST and running works from fiddler.

Also, perhaps because the method was switched to GET, there is no body captured in fiddler, I had to manually paste in the JSON

```
GET /*URL*/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: /*host*/
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: Possibly a bug, per this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105096/how-to-process-the-redirect-in-post-method-using-httpclient

Comment: I was receiving this when my url wasn't ending with `/`

Comment: My URL was not ending with /, that was the case for me as well @PiotrPerak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem appears to be that someone changed the URL without telling us, and they put a redirect in place. HttpClient is responding to the redirect, but ends up actually sending the request to the final destination as a Get.

This seems like a bug in HttpClient to me, that it should either send the ultimate request as a Post, or throw an exception saying it can't do what I asked it to.

See [Forwarding a response from another server using JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890635/forwarding-a-response-from-another-server-using-jax-rs/45893624#45893624)

Comment: Yeah maybe a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105096/how-to-process-the-redirect-in-post-method-using-httpclient  If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Comment: Turns out this was my issue as well. Re-writing an old app was still going to http:// server even though the new server is https:// with a redirect causing non secure connections to redirect to secure site.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue as mentioned by @Brad Moore.  In Azure, we enabled a security setting that requires all URL calls to use https://.  One of the old calls still doing a POST to an http:// endpoint and was logging a "Method Not Allowed" error, stating that the call was a GET which was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (golang server), the request had double slashes in the URI and the golang server was redirecting to the single slashed version of the URI. Inexplicably, `HttpClient` was using `GET` on the redirected URI instead of the original `POST`.

For example, I was mistakenly requesting `https://example.com//foo` and the server was redirecting me to `https://example.com/foo`.